# How to use JSON objects from root in UIViewController with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I want to parse a JSON with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

JSON to parse:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Cookie": "_gauges_unique_month=1; _gauges_unique_year=1; _gauges_unique=1", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
  }, 
  "origin": "150.107.254.75", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

I can access the 'args' but I can't access the 'Accept-Encoding' in my `UIViewController`'s `UILabel`

What I am trying in coding:

```
let Endpoint: String = "http://httpbin.org/get"
  Alamofire.request(Endpoint).responseJSON { response in
    if let json = response.result.value as? Array<Dictionary<String,Any>> {
      self.arrRes = json as [[String:AnyObject]]     
    }
  }
```

I want to use 'Headers' in my `UIViewController`'s `UILabel`.

Comment: The root object is not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to cast the json to an array, but it's a dictionary, try this:

```
let endpoint: String = "http://httpbin.org/get"
Alamofire.request(endpoint).responseJSON { response in
  if let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any],
     let headers = json["headers"] as? [String:Any] {

     self.label.text = headers["Accept-Encoding"] as? String
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, variables in swift start with lowercase